# Are there any benefits of using vue-class-component in Vue 3 projects?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, migration

I want to upgrade my project from **Vue 2** to **Vue 3**. In my project I was using `vue-class-component` and `vue-property-decorator` libraries but **Vue 3** supports **TypeScript** out of the box. The only one thing which I saw for now is that I can not use classifiers (`private`, `protected` or `public`) in methods or attributes declarations. Is it still worth to use those libraries or **TypeScript** support provided by **Vue 3** is perfectly sufficient ?

If there are any other pros or cons of *using / not using* these libraries please let me know.